# Using the All operator

Tags: .net, linq

I would like to see an example that makes the best use of the ALL operator when using a parent child reltaionship in LINQ. Can you show me one please?

Comment: Re your question (customers with order) - no; that would be Any - i.e. from cust in ctx.Customers where cust.Orders.Any() select cust;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The All() extension method checks a predicate against all the items; for example, at execution:

```
if(order.Lines.All(l=>l.IsClosed)) order.Close();
```

(checks all lines are closed, and if so, closes the order)

of in a query:

```
var qry = from order in ctx.Orders
         where order.CustomerId = id
         select new {
            order.OrderId,
            IsShipped = order.Lines.All(l => l.IsShipped)
         };
```

Comment: How would I handle a case where select all Customers having Order ..is this is a good candidate for 'All'?

Comment: no; that would be Any - i.e. from cust in ctx.Customers where cust.Orders.Any() select cust;

Answer (score 1):

Many LINQ examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the parents along with whether all its childrens are active.

```
from p in MyContext.Parents
select new
{
   p,
   ChildrensActive = p.Childrens.All(c=> c.IsActive)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<CD> goodCDs = CDs
  .Where(cd => cd.Songs.All(song => song.Rating > 6))
```